# Is this Matrix equation invalid?

Tags: linear-algebra

Matrix $\mathbf A$ is 3 by 3 ,
$\vec d$   is a column vector 3 by 1
$\vec x$ = $\vec d$ + $\mathbf A$$\vec x$

unknown is $\vec x$

and the procedure i followed in order to isolate $\vec x$

$\mathbf I$$\vec x$ - $\mathbf A$$\vec x$ = $\vec d$

$\vec x$($\mathbf I$-$\mathbf A$) = $\vec d$

$\vec x(\mathbf I - \mathbf A)^{-1}$ =$\vec d$$(\mathbf I - \mathbf A)^{-1}$

which finally leads to

$\vec x$ = $\vec d$$(\mathbf I - \mathbf A)^{-1}$

so my question the final step in equation is invalid multiplication as operands has 3X1 by 3X3

What did i do wrong on the equation?

Comment: 2nd equation: $(I-A)x = d$

Comment: How do you know that $I-A$ is invertible?

Answer (score 1):

This should be the correct way to solve:

$\mathbf I$$\vec x$ - $\mathbf A$$\vec x$ = $\vec d$

($\mathbf I$-$\mathbf A$)$\vec x$ = $\vec d$

$(\mathbf I - \mathbf A)^{-1}$ 
($\mathbf I$-$\mathbf A$) $\vec x$ =$(\mathbf I - \mathbf A)^{-1}$ $\vec d$

$\vec x$ = $(\mathbf I - \mathbf A)^{-1}$ $\vec d$

Comment: Assuming $\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{A}$ is invertible.

Comment: Correct, this possible if ||A||<1.

Comment: thanks a lot for all you guys , but i'm still confused about second step $(\mathbf I - \mathbf A)\vec x =\vec d $

Comment: sorry i forgot about non-commutativity of matrix multiplication

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the $2^{nd}$ step of your calculation. Matrix multiplication is [Non- Commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Non-commutativity) (i.e. $ \mathbf {A} \mathbf {B} \not = \mathbf  {B}\mathbf  {A}$ ) .The correct way to do this is as mentioned by @RedLapm.